# User Defined Dynamic Workflows in Workflow Foundation 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow-foundation-4

I have been, exhaustively, looking at examples of WF4 and am not sure it will work for my [project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451303/workflow-design-advice-for-asp-net-web-application). I need to be convinced otherwise. I am struggling with how we would implement a system to use WF4 so users have the ability to define workflows. It seems you need VS2010 experience to design and implement a WF4 workflow. I love wheat it can offer, but feel it may be too complicated for non techical users.

Do we just define a ton of custom activies that a user can move into a workflow? How can we make it as easy as possible for a user to build the workflow?

We have and application that we want to allow, Joe / Jane user to create their own workflows for specific items. For example, Request For Information items. The RFI has specific states it can be in that are defined by the user. They should be allowed to control the flow based on those states. There will be some base items that the application defines as to what will happen based on a decision / condition. So, things like notifications (who gets notified when something changes), time frames (how long something can stay in a certain state before something else happens), and possibly some other conditions. The conditions / decision types will be limited by the application, for now. But imagine they can build the workflow and add those decisions / conditions in without any coding knowledge.

I just don’t know how we can leverage WF4 in this way. Maybe I am looking at WF4 the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WF4 is capable of handling the workflows, but you need a simplified workflow editor to make the creation/modification of workflows available to end users.  This is possible with WF4.

If end-user definition and management of workflows is a requirement of your application then  I believe WF4 can be made to work in your case. It is possible to programmatically create and modify WF4 workflows before they are executed.

The best overall design might be a "workflow template" model where predefined workflows are provided by developers and expert users, then customized by end-users.  Users could configure "skeleton" workflows selected from a library of predefined templates.  This could get fairly complicated depending on your requirements.

On a side-note: the WF4 workflow designer is "hostable" in a Windows Forms/WPF application.  Expert users can define new workflows without having to use Visual Studio.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the "hostable" keyword when they described the designer. Since the application is completely web based, it has to be able to work in that environment.

Comment: If the application is 100% web-based then the hostable designer won't help you.  The WPF workflow designer you see in Visual Studio can be embedded in a Windows Forms or WPF application for editing workflows outside VS.

Comment: Exactly! That is my issue right now. So it seems to be possible to create custom activities that perform specific functions (like notifications and rules) and then we allow the users, through our own interface, build the workflow. We would have to store some sort of metadata in our database that would define the workflow, right? Can you think of an example of how this could work?

Comment: I don't know exactly how it work off the top of my head but you've got the right idea.  The approach I would take is to start small.  Predefine the workflow you want to make available, then decide on a set of well-defined attributes that are configurable by an end-user.  Once you get the hang of that, you can expand into more general cases and make your "workflow configurator" more capable and able to handle broader cases.

Comment: You need Visual Studio 2010 Professional or greater to be able to edit workflows in Visual Studio.  The express version doesn't come with the WF designer.

Comment: @DDiVita we have the same situation now were we need a User Defined Dynamic Workflow for our web based application. I was wondering if you would kindly shed some light on what you and your Team eventually implemented? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @superbDeveloper, we ended up building our own framework for this. We needed something that could have a web interface. I am not with that company anymore, but we used this as part of the interface: http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/jquery/demo.html

Comment: @DDiVita ya we also ended up doing the same thing by building our solution, anyway also no longer with that company anymore as well. thanks for link to demo, looks cool.