# C# Workflow Engine - For the end user

Tags: c#, sharepoint, workflow, workflow-foundation

All,

I am building a typical database driven helpdesk application.
I would like to enable the users to create workflows that will do the following types of tasks:

- Add a new ticket (a set of records in the database) at a given time
  of day, or date of the year, or a future date of some kind.
- If the ticket has a specific type of metadata such as a category and priority combination, it should set up an office outlook task and email it to someone.
- When the task gets updated, the task will update the next step in
  this workflow based on the response of the task.
- Etc…

I would use WFF, however in my case, I need to build the application that the end users will build the rules/workflows for, and the end users are average computer users.

Please give me some pointers, and some direction.

Bill

Comment: To give some perspective, I am trying to deploy a full application.  The application should have an interface that will allow the end users to create workflows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Nintex are trying to hit your problem on the head with thier [Workflow2010](http://www.nintex.com/en-US/Products/Pages/NintexWorkflow2010.aspx) product.

Comment: Ah, was confused by the question tag.

Answer (score 3):

You're able to host the Windows Workflow Foundation Designer within your application and give your users a custom set of activities.

By providing a custom set of activities you could ensure that users are able to use the designer with only a few workflow knowledge.

Another solution may be SharePoint. Microsoft SharePoint Foundation is shipped with every Windows Server 2008 R2. Older versions of Windows Server are shipping Windows SharePoint Services (Which is the free version of SharePoint 2007).

SharePoint is great in managing lists and listitems. SharePoint is built to make collaboration easier by using a great platform. The SharePoint platform itself allows you to run custom workflows based on items within lists.

So I think you should review your technical decision. And investigate a little more time in reviewing existing solutions that are achieving your requirements.

Thorsten

Comment: Here is a better example of what I am trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475893/user-defined-dynamic-workflows-in-workflow-foundation-4

Comment: As long as you're not interested in building transactional workflows SharePoint and Nintex would be the best option. When you're looking for more complex and process driven workflows, you should have a look at K2's Workflow Engine for SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Consider having a look at [Workflow Engine](https://workflowengine.io). It's a .NET component that enables you to update workflow steps with external commands/events, has timers, and, more importantly for you, a visual designer.