# User Defined Workflows Implementation

Tags: airflow, workflow

As part of our product requirements, we need to support a dynamic workflow configuration that will be set by the product's administrations.

Below is an example from Monday's system of this concept.
Meaning that the user can define the custom flow of event --> conditions / branches --> actions that will set the workflow.

Need to support events that are based on schedule and also on system configurations changes (an object changed it's state)

What is the best way to implement this on the back-end side? what module/tool should be used in order to execute the workflows?

We thought of the following design:

1. Create a workflow object for the whole workflow tree saving it as a hierarchical JSON object that contains the defined user hierarchy of the different objects (event, conditions, actions) and storing it in the database.
2. Use [Apache Workflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) as an orchestrator and create DAG **dynamically** based on the defined workflows and update them accordingly.

Is there a better tool to implement the following design? (saw some posts relating to this, but with no answer: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140613/user-defined-dynamic-workflows-and-user-input), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475893/user-defined-dynamic-workflows-in-workflow-foundation-4))

Thanks!

[image]